# Why django finds errors inside comment blocks in template?

Tags: python, html, django

Sometime Django finds an error in a template. I Would like to comment out the row to debug but django keeps to find the error even in the comment.

For example this link give me an error because `url 'prova'` don't exist.

```
<!--<a href="{% url 'prova' %}">Prova</a><br/>-->
```

another example: here `{{ field }}` give an error (and I don't know why but this is another problem)

```
   <!--{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label }}
    {{ field }}
    {{ field.help_text }}
    <br />
  {% endfor %}-->
```

Maybe there's another way to comment?

Thank you

Comment: I also ran into this issue, which perplexed me that the only reference to the view function I was having issue with was inside an HTML comment... I feel Django parser can easily identify HTML tags.. so I view this as a bug.  However, I could see the argument perhaps the Django developers made that they don't want Django code "leaking" into rendered HTML (could see this under view source).  That's the only reason I can see not to respect the HTML comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Django still parses the code; it doesn't care about HTML comments. If you want to ensure that it does not get rendered at all, you should use the Django comment tags, `{% comment %}...{% endcomment %}`.

For a single line, you can wrap things in `{# ... #}`.

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#comment).